# How do I listen for, load and run user-defined workflows at runtime that have been persisted using SqlWorkflowInstanceStore?

Tags: workflow, persistence, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

The result of SqlWorkflowInstanceStore.WaitForEvents does not tell me what type of workflow is runnable.  The constructor of WorkflowApplication takes a workflow definition, and at a minimum, I need to be able to store a workflow ID in the store and query it, so that I can determine which workflow definition to load for the WorkflowApplication.

I also don't want to create a SqlWorkflowInstanceStore for each custom workflow type, since there may be thousands of different workflows.

I thought about trying to use WorkflowServiceHost, but not every workflow has a Receive activity and I don't think it is feasible to have thousands of WorkflowServiceHosts running, each supporting a different workflow type.

Ideally, I just want to query the database for a runnable workflow, determine its workflow definition ID, load the appropriate XAML from a workflow definition table, instantiate WorkflowApplication with the workflow definition, and call LoadRunnableInstance().

I would like to have a way to correlate which workflow is related to a given HasRunnableWorkflowEvent raised by the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore (along with the custom workflow definition ID), or have an alternate way of supporting potentially thousands of different custom workflow types created at runtime.  I must also load balance the execution of workflows across multiple application servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a free product from Microsoft that does pretty much everything you say there, and then some. Oh, and it's excellent too.

Windows Server AppFabric. No, not Azure.
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/app-main.aspx

-Oisin

Comment: I am already running a Windows service that accepts NServiceBus messages to execute workflows.  I would have liked to use WorkflowApplication objects in process.  We also have workflows that do not begin with a Receive activity.  Do you know of a way to store a custom property that I can then subsequently access either via a Command sent to the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore or from the database directly?

Comment: Workflows can invoke child workflows. Have you considered creating a stub WCF worflow service for launching these workflows as child workflows? Then you could use appfabric. The child workflows don't need to have a receive event. Appfabric gives you persistence, tracking and monitoring, load balanacing and automatic scale out.

Comment: How can you make a single generic workflow type that invokes any child workflow? I have to support thousands of user generated workflow types.

Comment: Btw for wf4, you're not stuck with receive activites for triggers anymore. It's really hard to envisage what you want without details - but read up on the WCF router in wcf4 as a way to abstract the child workflow types maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have actually implemented my own workflow service.  I promote a Guid in the workflow instance store which references xaml that is stored in a custom workflow database.  (The workflow definition database and all associated services were already in place.)  I load up the xaml, create a WorkflowApplication, and then call Load with a runnable workflow instance id.  This was faster than reimplementing everything in AppFabric.